# Rewrite rule messes up direct links to directories

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a very simple rewrite rule which does the job: allows link `domain.com/index.php?page=NAME` to be displayed as `domain.com/NAME`.

The problem is when I try to give direct link to the image `www.domain.com/static/graphics/image.png`, the url rewrites to `www.domain.comstatic/graphics/image.png`. The slash after .com disappears and the image is not found.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

Is this is problem with .htaccess or my apache configuration?

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Any other `.htaccess` files? What is the exact link to your image in your HTML? Or are you directly requesting this in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line of code after `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteBase /
```